# Hiding cell Contains in MS Excel using SpreadSheetGear?

Tags: hide, cell, spreadsheet, spreadsheetgear

Hey any body know how to hide cell contains using spreadsheet gear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set IRange.NumberFormat to ";;;" to cause the contents of a cell to be hidden. There are also IRange.FormulaHidden, IRange.Rows.Hidden, IRange.Columns.Hidden and probably other ways to approach it that I am not thinking about. Here is some code which demonstrates these approaches:

```
namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a new workbook and get a reference to Sheet1!A1.
            var workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook();
            var sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            var a1 = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["A1"];
            // Put some text in A1.
            a1.Value = "Hello World!";
            // Set a number format which causes nothing to be displayed.
            //
            // This is probably the best way to hide the contents of 
            // a single cell.
            a1.NumberFormat = ";;;";
            // Set FormulaHidden to true - must set IWorksheet.ProtectContents 
            // to true for this make any difference. This will not hide values
            // in cells.
            a1.FormulaHidden = true;
            // Hide the row containing A1.
            a1.Rows.Hidden = true;
            // Hide the column containing A1.
            a1.Columns.Hidden = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Joe

Thank for giving hint,i got solution of my problem with hint given 
in your code,previously i was using  a1.NumberFormat = ";;;"
but it was not serving my requirements ,it was hiding cells contains but,cells contains ware visible in formula bar,now i am using a1.NumberFormat = ";;;" and   a1.FormulaHidden = true both
and this is working fine for my requirements .